# Android 4.2.2 'Not enough space on device', can't install apps

Tags: android, storage, android-sdcard

I've looked for a few different solutions but all of them involve rooting, or pre-rooted phones. Mine is not rooted (I'll do it if I have too, but I'm lazy.)

Basically, every time I try and update or download an app my phone says there's not enough space on the device, despite my 11GB on SD and 140MB internal, using the file manager.

Is there any solution that doesn't involve rooting?

(note: I tried dialing *#9900# and apparently it doesn't work because there isn't any signal. Guessing that means it won't work.)

I have an Alcatel One Touch Idol S, running 4.2.2 non-rooted.

Comment: I think http://android.stackexchange.com/ is a more appropriate site to ask for your problem, because it is not connected to coding.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Android device is different.  It all comes down to how the internal storage is partitioned.  Let's say your device has 8GB of RAM.  Maybe 1GB is partitioned for system storage.  This fills up fast.
Most applications need at least a portion installed on the system storage.  So even if you move the app to your SD card, or "internal storage", some part of it will have to remain in the system storage.  Plants Vs. Zombies, for instance, can be installed on the SD, but 50mb or so stays in the system.

For a start, you have to try to move as many apps as possible to the SD card.  Whatever you cannot move will have to be uninstalled.

Answer (score 3):

Settings > Apps > Google Play Store ... Click Uninstall Updates ... It will restore the factory version which works!

I had problems installing Skype on my Sony Experia E - "Not enough space on device" - It seems there is a problem with the latest updates to Google Play Store, so I uninstalled them and that solved the problem. Skype did not load first time due to an error with the package file but I tried again and it worked fine. I hope it works for you too.

Comment: I ended up moving as much as I could to external storage and reverted the google play store and this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="your package"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" 
android:installLocation="preferExternal">
```

use preferExternal in installLocation in your android manifest file

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by using below simple step

This is the easiest thing to do. Go to `settings` 
look for `storage` or `memory` touch it and look for `cached data`. `touch` it
and clear your data from there. SIMPLE!!!