# Apps not getting downloaded from play store

Tags: android, google-play-services

Today I tried to download application from play store and it showed the error 
"not enough storage space in device ", even though I have plenty of space left.
So I did some digging on the net and found some solutions like:

> go to settings > application > Google play services > clear cache > clear data force stop it and than do the same with  Google play store.

Then finally reboot the device and try to download the applications.
But it's not working for me.
What should I do? Please help me through this.

Comment: this question would be better suited for http://android.stackexchange.com/ i think?

Comment: This question is more suitable to [android.stackexchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: There are already some existing questions on this, try looking at these: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/81858/insufficient-space-on-the-device-but-my-sd-card-has-plenty-space http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25332899/android-4-2-2-not-enough-space-on-device-cant-install-apps

Answer (score 1):

In android device..
go to settings>more>Storage
you may find an option saying cache memory(Used to store intermediate or temporary results of services running in your phone)
click on it to clear the cached data(Not to worry this wont damage your device but may slow your mobile just for instance)
you can see lot space being occupied as cache when you are relentlessly using your mobile.
You get lot of space to download the app but installing depends on the overall expanded size of app.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you probably do not have enough space on the device.  How do you know that you have enough ?  If you are using a file explorer you can sometimes see a number of storage devices.  Are you looking at the right one ?  It will not install on the external sdcard (directly from play store).